# How do I determine what programs are running with root privileges?

Tags: linux, root

Is there a way to check via terminal which programs are currently running and by which privileges they run?

Comment: From `man ps`: *To see every process running as root (real & effective ID) in user format:* `ps -U root -u root u`. Or you can use a task manager that shows a 'user' column (top, htop, ksysguard, etc.).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ps -elf|grep root
```

Try this. Third field shows the process is running with root privileges